# Cannot Set Focus On TinyMCE From JQuery Click Event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick, tinymce, jquery-events

I have a link which when clicked, grabs some HTML and inserts it into TincyMCE, however I would then like to set focus on the editor but cannot get it to focus on the editor?

Here is my click method:

```
    $(".quotebutton").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var postid = $(this).attr('rel');
    var postcontentid = "#postcontent" + postid;
    var postcontent = "<pre>" + $(postcontentid).html() + "</pre>";
    tinyMCE.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, postcontent);
    tinyMCE.get('txtPost').focus();
    });
```

Any ideas why this isn't working? The HTML is being inserted, its just not focusing?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
tinyMCE.get('txtPost').execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, postcontent);//!!!
tinyMCE.get('txtPost').focus();
```